# How to make the header still visible even I scroll down?

Tags: html

Please visit this website: www.up.phinma.edu.com

I can't inspect through my Android Google Chrome browser so I need somebody's help.

Like the website you just preview a while ago I just want to ask you how to make a website with the header still visible even if you scroll down the webpage.

Comment: Your link does not show up! and not quoted as link

Comment: @MohammadKanan Let's keep it that way. All the information should be in the question itself.

Comment: @lvar, then no need for that link

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too specific to the question author. Questions should not require readers to visit external links, especially if they will shortly change once the problem is resolved.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
position:fixed;
```

You just need to add this CSS property to the header you've created. So that even after you scroll the header remains visible.

Comment: Wow is that it? Thanks a lot hehe I will try this

Comment: Sure, let us know if what you needed is accomplished.